# where can I see the print string when i add the code "System.out.println("test string");" in NameNode.java file?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Under NameNode.java file

Try to added test code of print string in main() function, the code as below:

System.out.println("test string");

where can I see the print string?

*code compiler successful and used new generation file(hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar) replace to each node.
*All daemon has restart. but not found the print string on terminal.

Comment: You should be able to see it in the stdout logs of your jobtracker node, under the particular job you were running.

Answer (score 0):

If you've restarted your name node service, these sys outs will probably go the the name node log file (which can be in a variety of locations depending on your hadoop disto / install). The hadoop-daemon.sh file defines the file as follows:

```
$HADOOP_LOG_DIR/hadoop-$HADOOP_IDENT_STRING-$command-$HOSTNAME.out
```

So you'll find it in the HADOOP_LOG_DIR, under the name `hadoop-$HADOOP_IDENT_STRING-nanmenode-$HOSTNAME.out` - where the other variables will be replaced depending on the runtime user and hostname of your namenode service.

I would suggest you use the predefined logger, rather then System.err / System.out:

```
LOG.info("log message");
```